# Flask request not returning any info from select

Tags: forms, flask, request, html-select

I'm trying to set up a simple select dropdown form with Flask.  Based on the option chosen, I grab different data from my database, and display it back into a div on my html template.  But I can't seem to get the Flask request to register any of the select options.  When I print request.form or request.args, I always get empty Dicts.  It's probably something simple I'm missing but I can't seem to find the problem.  I've gotten this to work with several input and button forms, but I can't get it to work right for selects.

Here is a bit of my html template code, with the form and select.  I've tried both GET and POST method in the form.

```
<div class="options" id="options">
    <form class="form-horizontal container-fluid" role="form" method="GET" action="exploresn2.html">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="xaxis" class="col-sm-2 control-label">X-axis:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <select name="xaxis" class="form-control" id="xaxis">
                    <option selected value="mjd" id="mjd">MJD</option>
                    <option value="seeing" id="seeing">Seeing</option>
                    <option value="airmass" id="airmass">Airmass</option>
                    <option value="hourangle" id="hourangle">Hour Angle</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>         
</div>
```

In Flask, at first, I tried inside my app

```
 import flask
 from flask import request, render_template, send_from_directory, current_app

 explore_page = flask.Blueprint("explore_page", __name__)

 @explore_page.route('/exploresn2.html', methods=['GET','POST'])
 def explore():

      xaxis = str(request.args.get("xaxis", "any"))

      .... [populate new xaxis variable based on request option selected]

      exploreDict['xaxis'] = xaxis
      return render_template("exploresn2.html", **exploreDict)
```

or

```
mjd = valueFromRequest(key='mjd', request=request, default=None)
if mjd:
    mjds = [int(exp.platedbExposure.start_time/(24*3600)) for exp in exposures]
    xaxis = mjds

exploreDict['xaxis'] = xaxis
```

to look for and grab a specific values, or in the first case, any value select.  The valueFromRequest is function that grabs data from either GET or POST requests.

but this returns nothing, and then I tried just printing the entire request.args (or request.form) and it returns and empty Dict.  Everything I try it still returns empty Dicts.  So I'm missing some set up somewhere I think but the form looks right to me?

Comment: I tried to reproduce the error with your code but everything just looks fine and working on my end. Can you see the option in url parameters (like `?xaxis=hourangle`) when the form is submitted?

Comment: No there are no url parameters.  That's most likely the problem but I don't see why I'm not getting any.

Comment: Strange. The problem is on clientside (browser) code then, not the flask view. Can you double check if you're using the correct endpoint path for `action` attribute in the form?

Comment: Yeah it should be.  It's just the name of the template html page the form is embedded in right?  The page that the form is associated with?  It's exploresn2.html.  That's the page I have this particular flask method assigned to.  Editing main post to include some bits on flask method.

Comment: So I fixed one thing.  The id in the first div had the same id name in the select element.  That was causing some confusion issues, and fixing that fixed other weird things, but it did not fix my request problem.  It's still not registering any of the url_parameters from the select GET method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the actual answer to this problem that I was looking for, but here is what I came up with.  I couldn't actually get the Flask to accept a GET request into the original explore method defined, so I implemented a new method in Flask to return a JSON object

```
@explore_page.route('/getdata', methods=['GET','POST'])
def getData(name=None):

     name = str(request.args.get("xaxis", "mjd"))
     xaxis = 'populate new xaxis data based on value of name'
     data = '(x,y) data array filled with values for plotting'
     axisrange = range of x,y data for axes for plot 

     return jsonify(result=data, range=axisrange)
```

and then I just made a GET request via javascript to that method whenever the select button changes.  So in my exploresn2.html template I have (using Flot for plotting)

```
$("#xaxis").change(function(){

    var newname = $("#xaxis :selected").text();
    var axes = plot.getAxes();
    options = plot.getOptions();
    var plotdata = plot.getData();

    // make a GET request and return new data       
    $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/getdata', {'xaxis':$("#xaxis :selected").val()},
            function(newdata){
                // set new data
                for (var i = 0; i < plotdata.length; ++i) {
                    plotdata[i].data = newdata.result[plotdata[i].label];
                }
                // set new axes
                axes.xaxis.options.panRange = [newdata.range[0]-50,newdata.range[1]+50];
                axes.xaxis.options.axisLabel = newname;
                axes.xaxis.options.min = newdata.range[0]-1;
                axes.xaxis.options.max = newdata.range[1]+1;
                axes.yaxis.options.min = newdata.range[2];
                axes.yaxis.options.max = newdata.range[3];                  
                // redraw plot
                plot.setData(plotdata);
                plot.setupGrid();
                plot.draw();
            });                
});
```